# How do I get the UIMA JCasGen to run in Eclipse? (OSX)

Tags: eclipse, macos, uima

I've installed the UIMA plugin, appears to work fine. I've also installed the UIMA SDK which also works fine.

The issue I have is that in the UIMA menu there is an option to run the JCasGen, but it never launches.

I can still run JCas Gen from the SDK manually in the Run configurations, but I'd like to get this menu option working.

Is there something extra that needs to be set for OSX?

```
Eclipse 4.2.0
UIMA 2.4.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to "Open with" > "Component Descriptor Editor"

Then in the "Type System" tab, click "JCasGen"

[image]

Comment: That button doesn't do anything either. I suspect it is a path issue in a setting somewhere. Run->Configurations->Run JCasGen and running it from the bin folder does work. So UIMA_HOME is set up correctly.

Comment: ok, the button works fine for me. What version of Eclipse do you use? I have never heard of 4.2? (I have the latest 3.7). Maybe try to install a clean Eclipse?

Comment: Running Eclipse Juno. Version: 4.2.0 Build id: I20120608-1400. Latest version. http://www.eclipse.org/juno/ . It is a clean install of Eclipse.